# WordPress - single.php is called twice for every post view

Tags: php, wordpress

In order to build the number of times a post was viewed I added simple tracking code into my theme single.php template file and a function in functions.php file.

After that I was wondered as I’ve got that the counter is incremented by two on each time a single post is viewed. I have checked and verified the post counter logic and its working fine, Even I **tried by removing that piece of code** and added a log statement on top of single.php page, which simple writes the post id and the time when the page was called into a log file. I always got two entries there.

I have also checked by disabling all the plug-ins but nothing worked.

WordPress version is **3.9.1**, Theme being used is [**Hueman**](http://wordpress.org/themes/hueman)

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823331/wordpress-single-php-called-twice) also didn't helped me.

**NOTE**: Code for the post view count have been roll-back. But still I have the same problem, infect post view count feature was the one who told me about this :)

Can anyone please suggest me what could be the reason of this behaviour?

Comment: Can you please tell us which WordPress theme you are using? Is it a standard one like Twenty Twelve or is it a custom one (built or bought)? Are you maybe using a child theme and can you perhaps show us the (regarding) code in single.php and functions.php?

Comment: @Jeina : I have updated the questions, and I hope this time I was more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you wrote it, it could be being called from functions.php and single.php. If you show us a bit of code, then it could really help.

Comment: Can you post the code that you use for tracking or just logging, and can you let me know where you put it in single.php? Currently, there seems to be no particular reason (**depending on where you put the code**) as to why you would get such results with the code in single.php. As for it still logging after you removed the code: the only thing that currently makes sense is if you have some caching methods that haven't been cleared, so the code is, for all intents and purposes, still there. Try clearing **all** the caching layers and see if the code still executes.